Conflict between tcolorbox and minted v3.1.1
My system:

Windows 11
TeX Live 2024 (updated: 2024-10-06)

minted v3.1.1
tcolorbox v6.4.0



I have a LaTeX document in which I use both minted and tcolorbox. Unfortunately, after updating TeX Live, I experience a conflict between the two packages. I made an MWE to demonstrate this:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted}

\newtcblisting{latex}{
  listing only,
  listing engine  = minted,
  minted language = latex,
  minted style    = default,
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{latex}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
1. Hello, World!
\end{document}
\end{latex}

\begin{latex}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
2. Hello, World!
\end{document}
\end{latex}

\begin{latex}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
3. Hello, World!
\end{document}
\end{latex}

\begin{latex}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
4. Hello, World!
\end{document}
\end{latex}

\begin{latex}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
5. Hello, World!
\end{document}
\end{latex}

\begin{latex}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
6. Hello, World!
\end{document}
\end{latex}

\begin{latex}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
7. Hello, World!
\end{document}
\end{latex}

\begin{latex}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
8. Hello, World!
\end{document}
\end{latex}

\begin{latex}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
9. Hello, World!
\end{document}
\end{latex}

\begin{latex}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
10. Hello, World!
\end{document}
\end{latex}

\begin{latex}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
11. Hello, World!
\end{document}
\end{latex}

\begin{latex}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
12. Hello, World!
\end{document}
\end{latex}

\end{document}

When compiling, I get the following error:
! No room for a new \read.
\e@ch@ck ...message {No room for a new \string #4}
                                                  \fi \fi 

If I delete the last latex environment, then the code works fine.
If I load the minted2 package before the tcolorbox, the code also works fine.
I'm not sure which package is causing the error, but if I just use the minted v3.1.1 package without tcolorbox, I don't get a similar error.
After the update, should I use something extra, or is this a fault of one of the packages?

If I temporarily remove one of the code blocks, successfully compile the document and then add the code block back, it still seems to work.

looks like a badly placed read allocation:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted}

\newtcblisting{latex}{
  listing only,
  listing engine  = minted,
  minted language = latex,
  minted style    = default,
  }


  \makeatletter

  \newread\minted@intempfile % just allocate once
  \def\minted@iffasthighlightmode@buffertempfile@iv{%
  \begingroup
  \setcounter{minted@tmpcodebufferlength}{0}%
% not here  \newread\minted@intempfile
  \openin\minted@intempfile=\minted@inputfilepath
  \endlinechar=-1%
  \let\do\@makeother\FVExtraDoSpecials
  \loop\unless\ifeof\minted@intempfile
    \read\minted@intempfile to\minted@intempfileline
    \stepcounter{minted@tmpcodebufferlength}%
    \expandafter\global\expandafter\let\csname
      minted@tmpcodebufferline\arabic{minted@tmpcodebufferlength}%
      \endcsname\minted@intempfileline
  \repeat
  \closein\minted@intempfile
  \expandafter\ifx\csname
      minted@tmpcodebufferline\arabic{minted@tmpcodebufferlength}%
      \endcsname\@empty
    \expandafter\global\expandafter\let\csname
      minted@tmpcodebufferline\arabic{minted@tmpcodebufferlength}%
      \endcsname\minted@undefined
    \addtocounter{minted@tmpcodebufferlength}{-1}%
  \fi
  \endgroup
  \edef\minted@inputfilemdfivesum@check{\pdf@filemdfivesum{\minted@inputfilepath}}%
  \ifx\minted@inputfilemdfivesum@check\minted@inputfilemdfivesum
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
   {\VerbatimClearBuffer[buffername=minted@tmpcodebuffer]}%
  \ifnum\value{minted@tmpcodebufferlength}>0\relax
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \else
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \fi
   {\minted@iffasthighlightmode@buffertempfile@v}}

  \makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{latex}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
1. Hello, World!
\end{document}
\end{latex}

\begin{latex}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
2. Hello, World!
\end{document}
\end{latex}

\begin{latex}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
3. Hello, World!
\end{document}
\end{latex}

\begin{latex}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
4. Hello, World!
\end{document}
\end{latex}

\begin{latex}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
5. Hello, World!
\end{document}
\end{latex}

\begin{latex}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
6. Hello, World!
\end{document}
\end{latex}

\begin{latex}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
7. Hello, World!
\end{document}
\end{latex}

\begin{latex}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
8. Hello, World!
\end{document}
\end{latex}

\begin{latex}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
9. Hello, World!
\end{document}
\end{latex}

\begin{latex}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
10. Hello, World!
\end{document}
\end{latex}

\begin{latex}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
11. Hello, World!
\end{document}
\end{latex}

\begin{latex}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
12. Hello, World!
\end{document}
\end{latex}

\end{document}

I'll open an issue
